# send "&" in url angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using the Angular version 12
I want to send the following object in query params:

```
{
  dynamicQueryOperators: 6&dynamicQueryOperators=8
}
```

But in the end, the URL that is sent to the server is like this
Request URL:

```
...dynamicQueryOperators=6**%26**dynamicQueryOperators=8
```

How can I prevent `"&"` from changing to `"%26"`?

Comment: I'm no angular master, but maybe you could just throw a `decodeURIComponent` at the other end.
for example `decodeURIComponent("you %26 me") == 'you & me'`

Comment: If you don't let it be encoded it will be treated as the start of a new query parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the bug by sending the variable as an array.
If you send the variable like below:

```js
this.query['dynamicQueryOperators'] = [6, 8];
```

Your header will be automatically created with two identical object keys and the character "&" will be placed between them.